# How to save images from HTML form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

```
class Product(models.Model):
      product_name      = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      product_rate      = models.IntegerField()
      product_date      = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
      product_image     = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
      product_rules     = models.TextField()
      product_category  = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)



def __str__(self):
    return " Name: {} | Date: {}".format(self.product_name,self.product_date)
```

[this is my product model]
using this model I can save data into my database. and I can also retrieve data and then I can show that into a browser.

But when I am trying to save the data from HTML form everything goes to my database but I can't see the image on my media folder.

when I save an image from the admin panel I can see the image in the media folder but not from HTML form.

```
   <input type="file" name="product_image" id="product_image">
```

This is my Views function for saving this data into database

```
def addproducts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_name= request.POST.get('product_name')
        product_rate= request.POST.get('product_rate')
        product_rules= request.POST.get('product_rules')
        product_image = request.POST.get('product_image')
        Product.objects.create(product_name = product_name, product_rate =product_rate, product_rules =product_rules, product_image =product_image)

        return redirect('products')

    else:
        print("error")

    return render(request,'products/addproducts.html')
```

It works properly except that image. But I can still see the image name from the ADMIN PANEL.

What i did wrong? :/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to process the file manually, but I would not recommend it. 
Manually processing the data from a POST request is unsafe and prone to errors.

[`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) is a perfect way to handle this.

Simply create a ModelForm class:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Product
         fields = ['product_name', 'product_rate', 'product_rules', 'product_image']
```

then simply create your `Product` from the POST data:

```
def addproducts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('products')

    else:
        print("error")

    return render(request,'products/addproducts.html')
```

`form.is_valid()` will also check if the request sent is valid.